# how the inner join can be nested?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am newbie in `SQL` and practicing queries for my university assignments...I have three tables in the database:

**1. student:**

```
studentid pk

fname

school
```

**2. books:**

```
bookid pk

bookname
```

**3. issue:**

```
issueid pk

studentid fk

bookid fk

fine
```

and I am trying to solve this query:

**select the `bookname` and the average `fine` for those students who have issued two or more books.**

I have tried using nested `INNER JOIN`s as:

```
 SELECT fname,bookname,AVG(fine) FROM 

    student INNER JOIN ( books INNER JOIN issue ON books.bookid=issue.bookid) ON 

    student.studentid=issue.issueid

GROUP BY fname

HAVING COUNT(bookid)>1;
```

but failed.Is there any mistake or is it totally wrong to nest `JOIN`s as above? Or please hint me if there is an another way to do this using `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two separate joins:

```
SELECT fname,bookname,AVG(fine)
FROM student
INNER JOIN issue ON student.studentid=issue.issueid
INNER JOIN books ON books.bookid=issue.bookid 
GROUP BY fname
HAVING COUNT(bookid)>1;
```

Another possibility is to join on several tables in the same `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT fname,bookname,AVG(fine)
FROM student
INNER JOIN (issue, books) ON (student.studentid=issue.issueid AND books.bookid=issue.bookid)
GROUP BY fname
HAVING COUNT(bookid)>1;
```

The reason your query was wrong is simply that you did not use the right syntax...: there is no such thing as nested joins.

[This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) is the MySQL documentation page for joins. You will find many examples of how to handle joins.

Comment: You were wrong simply because you did not use the right syntax. I will try to do my best to add more information on my answer.

Comment: thanks..If you give the example of what you have done then it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work. You can append INNER JOINs after each other, and use the values of any previously called tables after the ON parameter.

```
SELECT student.fname, books.bookname, AVG(issue.fine)
FROM student
INNER JOIN issue ON issue.studentid = student.studentid
INNER JOIN books ON books.bookid = issue.bookid
GROUP BY student.fname
HAVING COUNT(books.bookid)>1
```

Comment: julienc's answer is not correct, because you have to put the table name (or at least it's alias, if set) in front of the column name. Also, julienc binded the issue table on issue table's issueid, which should have been studentid.

Comment: You don't have to put an alias if there is no ambiguity. And the term order in the `ON ... = ...` does not matter at all.

Comment: It's not about the term order. You've wrote student.studentid = issue.issueid. The correct one should have been student.studentid = issue.studentid. You were referencing on the wrong value.

Comment: Hum, ok for this one. Actually, I copied and past the OP's query, and the error was already in it...

Comment: I've checked the other issue, and you're right. All the column names in the SELECT statement are unique, so it's not necessary to append the table name or its alias in front of it.